# SQL Server Restore Checkpoint File

Tags: sql-server, database

When restoring a database I am noticing a temporary Checkpoint.ckp file being created in the default backup directory. Can anyone tell me what these files do during the restore process

Answer (score 5):

When your restore operation will fail you can continue it with the WITH RESTART option - look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187851.aspx

The information where the restore operation should be continued from, is stored in a .ckp file.

If you will delete this file and then try to restore with a "WITH RESTART" option, you will get an error described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/1c78bead-b9f7-4025-a10a-e8d4183f089b

This feature is very useful in a subsequent restore ( when your restore was failed on 15 from 20 files).